# Angular country icons showing

Tags: angular, flags, country

I need some help with Angular. I have downloaded lots of country icons library (svg icons) from flat icon and want to use them to show them based on the country inside my project. They are plenty of icons so what would be the easiest way to do it instead if or switch condition. I am talking about 870 icons

Comment: Here is a wheel https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-flag-icons maybe you don't need to reinvent it.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own pipe, and use it in the MTHL, like this:

```
<img [src]=" object.country | yourImagePipe">
```

If *object.country*='ES', then in the HTML should be load the spanish icon (sor instance, with name es.svg)

And an example of pipe which which does this, would be this pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'yourImagePipe',
})
export class YourImagePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
  
  let urlImg: string = 'assets/imgs/yourCountryImages/';

    switch (value) {
      case 'ES':
        urlImg += 'es.svg';
        break;

      case 'UK':
        urlImg += 'uk.svg';
        break;

      case 'FR':
        urlImg += 'fr.svg';
        break;
      
      default:       
        urlImg = 'unknowImage.svg';
        break;
    }

    return urlImg;
  }
}
```

You only have to fit the paths and icons names to yours, and your problem will be solve!